# Why do I get 'no usage found in All places' message in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I cloned [this repository](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base.git).

Then opened `base` folder as Project root in IntellijIDEA and opened `Activity.java` file.

When I select `attach` method inside `Activity.java` file and press ⌥F7, IntellijIDEA show `no usage found in All place`.

But `ActivityThread` class inside the same directory of `Activity` class use the `attach` method of it.

Why do I get `no usage found in All places` message?

Answer (score 2):

It's a very small process you just go to the menu bar and click on File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart and you are good to go.

Comment: I tried twice. but it's not working for me.

Comment: Same here. Invalidating cache does not seem to help in my case.